# Microsoft Access to MySQL Database Converter

Tags: database, mysql, microsoft-access

I am working on creating a basic master-detail application using `VB.NET` and `MySQL`, because of this I've tried to look for a simple master-detail application using VB.NET in the internet and I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/835501/Master-Detail-Datagridview).

The problem is that, the database of the example is MS Access, what I want is to use MySQL.

Question: Can you recommend a software to convert `MS Access` to `MySQL`? I prefer if it is free, web-based is also okay as long as I can effectively convert `MS Access` to `MySQL`.

Comment: Did you think of setting up and odbc connection to connect to mysql from MsAccess.  There is a mysql driver for windows.  Also are you trying copy just data, or are there triggers/stored procedures, and etc?

Comment: I don't know about setting up an ODBC Connection Sir, seems too complicated for me? The `MS Access` has `tables` and `queries` only, no `stored procedures`.

Comment: You could export the tables as CSV file and import them into mysql using something like this for the import **LOAD DATA INFILE **.  You could use the describe command to describe each table.  Then you use that to create the tables in mysql.  Interested?

Comment: @cybernard Yes, seems too simple. I would like to try it.